# Excluding specific files from the mobile redirection rule using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mobile

I use this code to redirect mobile users:

```
#mobile redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

And this code to exclude a file from this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/addNames.php$ $0 [L]
```

(before the mobile redirect)

But the exclusion rule doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Maybe because it should not have leading slash `/` in URL pattern when placing in .htaccess (check docs) ?? Try the same but without `/`. 2) Instead of separate rule ... why not add another condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/addNames\.php` ?

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, the condition did it.